# Invert a transcendental function

Tags: inverse, equation-solving

I have tried `Reduce` and `Solve` in Mathematica, as well as have a long list of tries in Maple, but cannot seem to get anywhere solving the following for `V`:

```
V^P * (V-1)^Q == c^(P-Q) * X^Q * (V-c^2)^Q,
```

where `P`,`Q` are positive integers; `V>0`; `U>0` and `X = U^Q * V^P`; `c = Exp[t/2]` where `t` is `i` times a real number.

Any suggestions would be great.

Btw, I can share a Maple file (http://ubuntuone.com/5WGrFF8PYXR8LSwNB95SRW) where I tried a Fixed-Point/Contraction attempt, a series inverse attempt, and even the Lagrangian Inversion method. For the most part I seem to run out of computing power when I try to get to decent orders of approximation...

P.S. I am looking for a symbolic solution, at least to a few orders.

Comment: Are you looking for a symbolic or numerical solution?

Comment: So you are looking a symbolic approximation for `V` in terms of `U` while the rest (`P`,`Q`,`c`) are parameters?

Comment: Well eventually I need `V(X)`, either as a polynomial... and yes, `P`, `Q`, and `c` are parameters.

Comment: Here's a way to invert just about any equation: `Rotate[V^P*(V - 1)^Q == c^(P - Q)*X^Q*(V - c^2)^Q, Pi]`

Comment: @bills, you're missing a `HoldForm` :)

Comment: By carelessly moving powers from here to there (I renamed V y and went lowercase for all letters), I ended up with `x==(y/c)^(p/q) c (y-1)/(y-c^2)`. Is that what you want to invert? Have you tried to plot it for some values of your constants?

Comment: Hi, yes I did plot the function I wanted to invert, with various values of "c". It is invertible. Turns out that in the solving scheme of Mathematica, I was using a "sum" as an ansatz (to plug back into the equation) when I should have been using a "series". I guess the big-O was needed by Mathematica... Thanks!